# ExcelDataReader - Get index of currently read row

Tags: c#, .net-core, exceldatareader

I'm using ExcelDataReader to read .xlsx files.

```
using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
{
    for (bool canRead = true; canRead; canRead = reader.NextResult())
    {
        //reader.Read(); many times
    }
}
```

How to get the index of the row I'm currently reading? In other words, how many times `reader.Read()` has been called.

Comment: Declare a `int` variable before the `for` and increment it inside the `for`.

Comment: @mjwills, `reader.Read()` may be called many times every iteration. I know I can use some counters and constants, but it's inconvenient to modify.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
using (var stream = File.Open("Book1.xls", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read))
{
    using (var reader = ExcelReaderFactory.CreateReader(stream))
    {
        do
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Row: {reader.Depth} Values: {reader[0]}, {reader[1]}");
            }
        } while (reader.NextResult());
    }
}
```

Output
[image]